# Hide line from legend

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I need to hide 4 lines from the legend. I'm using [shadedErrorBar](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26311-shadederrorbar) so I have 3 line for a sigle group (mean, upper edge of standard deviation and bottom edge) and if i use the classic code `legend('line1','line2,'...)` I'll have 3 label. I want in the legend only the mean for each group.
I have 2 groups.

```
shadedErrorBar(x,y1,e1);
shadedErrorBar(x,y2,e2);
```

`y1` and `y2` are my means, while `e1` and `e2` standard deviations. 
I think I should use IconDisplayStyle but I don't understand how. I read this http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/controlling-legends.html but is like hide a `plot` to hide a line. With shadedErrorBar I have a graph with 3 plot on it for each group.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot everytime. I'll add a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the legend, [you can specify only the plot objects that you would like to create legend entries for](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#inputarg_obj). The output of `shadedErrorBars` is a struct containing all of the plot objects so you can use these to grab the patch objects and create legend entries for *only* those.

```
h1 = shadedErrorBar(linspace(1,10), linspace(1,10), linspace(0,1));
hold on
h2 = shadedErrorBar(linspace(1,10), linspace(1,20), linspace(1,0));

legend([h1.patch, h2.patch], {'Item1', 'Item2'})
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want show lines on the legend instead of two colored boxes?

Comment: @Shika93 Look at the other fields of `h1` and `h2` and use the appropriate ones in a similar way.

Comment: `legend([h1.lin, h2.lin], {'Item1', 'Item2'})`?

Comment: @Shika93 Is that what value the outputs have for you? For me it looks like it would be `[h1.mainLine, h2.mainLine]`